# Extra index.php ? added in Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.2.0 Version and configured sub domain (*.domainname.in) in my hosting. Below is my .htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Above .htaccess configuration Works for below Urls

```
domainname.in ----> domainname.in
www.domainname.in --------> domainname.in
www.pune.domainname.in -----> pune.domainname.in
```

But when I try to access my auth controller using this URL `http://pune.domainname.in/auth`

It redirect to below URL with **index.php?**

```
http://pune.domainname.in/index.php?/auth
```

Here is the original domain Url

Can you please suggest why it is happening

Thanks

Comment: change $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = ''; in application/config/config.php

Comment: @Vicky This is the only content in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes my .htaccess file contains above configuration

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess? Also where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava - There is no other rule and .htaccess file is located under dir public_html/businesswale.in/.htaccess

Comment: But `http://pune.businesswale.in/auth` is giving me 500 internal server error. Can you check Apache error.log to see what this error is?

Comment: did changes in .htaccess as suggested by "Lokesh Jain"

Comment: Hmm that looks buggy in one look

Comment: Also I like to know where is CI touting rule in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

just put that code in .htaccess file and try it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / businesswale.in/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No luck still persist the same problem

Comment: is your codeigniter project in some folder or is it in root?

Comment: Here is the project location public_html/businesswale.in/application and public_html/businesswale.in/system

Comment: is businesswale.in a folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63430/discussion-between-vicky-and-lokesh-jain).

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your_projct_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```